# How to use join on recent record in db_select drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-database

I have two tables.

```
Table One 
xx
yy
zz

Table Two
xx-3
xx-2
xx-1
yy-2
yy-1
zz-4
zz-3
zz-2
zz-1
```

I want to use join between these 2 tables in such a way that it will use latest record from Table Two for each record of table One.
i.e. xx join with xx-3
yy join with yy-2
and zz join with zz-4

query will go like this:

```
$query = db_select('One', 'o');
$query->leftJoin('Two', 't', 't.column1 = o.column1');
$query->fields('o',array('column1','column2'));
$query->fields('t',array('column1','column2'));
$query->orderBy('o.column1', 'DESC');
```

How can I do this using db_select in Drupal 7?

Comment: Please define your table fields in separated column.

Comment: Why are you making custom queries? If you want to do that use some framework, not cms. Use the views module for queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$query = db_select('Two', 't');
$query->join('One', 'o', 'o.column1 = t.column1');
$query->fields('t',array('column1','column2'));
$query->orderBy('t.column1', 'DESC');
$res = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Okay i updated my answer as you defined the One tables has only one column so you just need to get only Two table fields, now try.